# How can I arrange my project files according to their folder structure in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, shell, applescript

I am working on a MASSIVE project with about 10 thousand files in it. The files are nicely arranged in Xcode's directory system but not so on the disk. Is there a tool that I could use that would make the folder structure on my disk represent the folder structure in Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I know two ways to do it:

- Do it manually (rearrange your folder first, and then drag and drop your directories in xcode). That will do the job.
- Use an external library, I suggest you [synx](https://github.com/venmo/synx). It does the job well

I don't know why you want to do that, but I don't think it's really important if your folder isn't ordering with your xcodeproj since you will always open it with xcode. Just separate assets is enough, isn't it?